# "Not well-formed" firefox error while looping through JSON file with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, angularjs

The JSON file structure is as follows:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20, 
        "next": null, 
        "offset": 0, 
        "previous": null, 
        "total_count": 2
    }, 
    "objects": [
        {
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ....", 
            "end": "2013-09-09T15:37:24", 
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", 
            "resource_uri": "/api/task/1/", 
            "start": "2013-09-09T15:37:23"
        },
        {
            "description": "Here goes description :) Here goes description :) Here goes description :) ", 
            "end": "2013-09-11T15:58:01", 
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Some other task", 
            "resource_uri": "/api/task/2/", 
            "start": "2013-09-11T15:58:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was trying to loop through it like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app id="ng-app">
    <head>
        <title>Angular studies</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http) {
        $http({method: 'POST', url: 'posts.json'}).success(function(data) {
                $scope.tasks = data;
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax"> 

        <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
           <a href='{{task.id}}'>{{task.name}}</a>
        </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for this I'm getting "Not well-formed" error in Firefox. Can you please show me a way to mend this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but do you need to parse the JSON before you can use it?

Comment: Hmmm, I tried serializing and deserializing your json with Newtonsoft and it worked just fine. If you like I'll post my code.

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294432/angularjs-http-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found-location-error-when-expect/53523757#53523757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed valid JSON. The problem is that you try to iterate over `tasks`, but in fact want to iterate over `tasks.objects`

```
for (var i=0;i<tasks.objects.length;i++) {
    console.log(tasks.objects[i].id);
    console.log(tasks.objects[i].name);
}
```

outputs

```
1 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
2 
Some other task
```

I am not familiar with the angular syntax, but I guess this is what you want / really try to do :

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks.objects">
```