# Angularjs $http "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location" error when expecting JSON results on GET

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

When I submit an **angularjs** `$http` GET call I receive an XML parsing error.

The $http call code snippet is:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "myapp/api/items" + itemId
 });
```

The error is:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{f191853f-5581-b049-b83f-5f4b69211adb} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

The data being returned is JSON. If I put the URL in a browser then the request is submitted and the response data comes back successfully in the browser.

I tried adding `responseType: 'json'` (and `responseType: 'application/json'`) to the `$http` call with no success. (I referenced the Usage section in [angularjs http](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/%24http) doc to determine how to configure the call.)

Is there a way I can force the response data to be recognize as json to avoid that error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mozilla Firefox, install firebug and try to inspect the http GET in the Net panel or in the Console panel.

In the headers tab you can check the Content-Types being sent and received. Maybe the problem is in the server-side response's content-type.

Comment: I use firebug to evaluate requests and responses. The response for the same uri is different when I issue it from the browser url box (or curl) than when it is issued from the angularjs $http call.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are running your app in `file:///`, since this is AJAX request this can be happen. If you have installed nodejs, you can install a server and see console log.

To install a server on nodejs

```
npm install -g http-server
```

And go to(`cd` into) your project directory and:

```
http-server -o. -o
```

Now see the browser console.